# Would IUnitOfWork will fit in my scenario

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I have been reading about UnitOfWork pattern for last two days but didn't understand it correctly.

I have a repository for each class. 
eg.
Employee, Attendance, Salary, Department, Address etc.

Repository means- Each of these classes will have their own CRUD operations(creates own database connection). These creates separate database connection and do insert.

Issue arises when I want to do multiple operations as atomic. eg. Insert into Employee and Address in a single transaction. But my repositories do not allow so because Employee is responsible to manage Employee table only.

I can use System.Transactions but this will drive me crazy because of numerous database connections for a single transaction.

Would UoW applies to my case but making some changes?

EDIT:

My sample code

```
public class AccountTransactionManager
{
    Properties.Settings settings = new Properties.Settings();

    public void InsertAccountTransaction(AccountTransaction accountTransaction)
    {
        SqlParameter AccountId = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@AccountId", Value = accountTransaction.AccountId, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int };
        SqlParameter PAYMENT_DATE = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@PAYMENT_DATE", Value = accountTransaction.PAYMENT_DATE, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime };
        SqlParameter CURRENT_BALANCE = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@CURRENT_BALANCE", Value = accountTransaction.CURRENT_BALANCE, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Money };

        Helper.SqlHelper.Execute(settings.SQLConnectStr
            , (tran) =>
            {
                Helper.SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(tran, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "usp_AccountTransactionInsert", AccountId, PAYMENT_DATE, CURRENT_BALANCE);
            });
    }
}
```

SqlHelper code

```
public static void Execute(string connectionString, Action<SqlTransaction> CallBack)
{
    if (CallBack == null)
        return;

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var tran = con.BeginTransaction())
        {
            #region Call procedures

            try
            {
                CallBack(tran);
                tran.Commit();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                tran.Rollback();
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

Requirements will be changing very frequently. So should I use any ORM or create my own repository. Would I be able to use stored procedures in ORM?

Comment: I don't see what an ORM has to do with changing requirements.  If you mean that your data model will change frequently, then you need to change it anyways.. so ORM or DAL doesn't matter.

Comment: @MystereMan: Yes my data model will be changing frequently as well as I am moving in an incremental approach for an application development. Requirements are not known at this level.

Comment: Again, you have to change your code whether you use an ORM or not, I don't see any difference here or any reason to be concerned about using an ORM because of this.  Lots of people do iterative development using ORM's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some very wrong assumptions there.  First, just because you have two repositories, it doesn't mean you have two database connections if you use both of them.  Database connections are pooled by most ORM's such as Entity Framework and nHibernate.  So you don't know how connections will be handled, but you can generally be assured that when you call SaveChanges, it will have an implied transaction and occure as a single atomic action.

Second, you're ignoring one of the key benefits of an ORM, which is navigational properties and collections.  If you have an Employee table, then it should have an Address navigational property or Collection of Addresses.

So, say you want to insert a new Employee.  You create a new Employee entity, and then create a new Address entity, then add the Address to the Employee, then add the employee to your ORM.  When you call Commit or SaveChanges or whatever causes your ORM to update, it updates both entities and it happens as a single transaction.

Likewise, if you add multiple employees, all of them are added as a single transaction when you call SaveChanges.

You would really only need to use System.Transaction if you believe a distributed transaction might be needed.  Or, you truly have a multi-step process that cannot be done in a single unit of work.

Much of what you're talking about is based on assumptions that each Repository is it's own stand alone unit of work, that is not a necessary assumption at all.  UnitOfWorks can be shared between all your repositories.  This is even easier to accomplish if you're using Dependency Injection.

EDIT:

Based on your edit, I see you're not using an ORM, but rather using a Repository to handle your DAL.  Some of what I said still applies, you don't need each repository to have its own connection, and you don't need to have a repository only deal with a single entity, as entities have related entities that can be managed as well.

The important thing to remember about UnitOfWork is that it's a sort of entity cache.  You add or update dirty entities to it, and it doesn't save them one by one... instead, it waits until you call Save, and then it does them all in a single transaction.

Further, a Repository is not a Unit of work, it's more of a wrapper around a UnitOfWork.  Your UnitOfWork keeps track of all entities in the model, not just a single one.  So multiple repositories can share a single UnitOfWork.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta - There are a million implementations of repositories out there, and a million different ways of doing it.  I can't tell you how you should write it, because I don't know your requirements, or your data model, or anything else.  However, the problem is not the transaction object, but rather how you're structuring your data access in general.

Answer (score 1):

The UnitOfWork pattern is used to manage the state of a Model object and whether it needs to be saved to the database.

The best way of thinking about it is if you change a property on your Model object then the object knows that it has been changed (usually it is marked as dirty) and then this object is handled by a persistence mechanism. You may have 10 objects in an IList - you change 2 of them - when it's time to save the persistence layer knows that only 2 have changed and only saves those to the database.

You can read up more about how this works [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx)

By the sounds of things the real issue you are having is how you create your persistence layer (your repositories). What you need is some form of single connection management object that holds the connection to your database but does it in a way that is accessible by all the repositories in your assembly. What you need is a Singleton object, probably created using a static Factory pattern.

Now to be honest, this is a fairly low level bit of data access code and managing the transaction (committed, under transaction etc) and connection state (open, closed) can be a troublesome bit of code. These days there are a number of frameworks like nHibernate, Entity Framework and Active Record that do all this stuff for you (ironically using many of the patterns you describe).

EDIT: Just saw your code. If you really, really want to do it yourself then remove the static keyword from your SQLHelper class, move the connection code out into seperate methods called open and close and wrap the SQLHelper class in a new static Factory class that always returns a single instance (Singleton).

Comment: Thanks for response. I never worked on any ORM so bit hesitant. I have read about EF and little afraid about what will be the impact on code on a frequently changing requirements. How to use it with WCF services. Designing an entity is also a challenge to me

Comment: I read about mapping scenarios of EF but again I was not clear with most of these http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716779.aspx which made me decide not to go for EF

Comment: I use nHibernate for my ORM and Castle Windsor as an IoC container (it can manage things like Singletons). If you want to have a look at this kind of architecture in action then I would suggest having a look at Sharp Architecture. You may not end up using it but its very good to see how someone else is doing it.